# do not work properly duplicate entry validation in php using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have create multiple forms, this form hide and show after change a drop down value
I wank to check duplicate entry on click on submit button
than add this code 
but this code do not work properly

```
jQuery('#form_1').on('submit', function(event) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: SITE_URL+'/admin/ajax/function.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: jQuery('#form_1').serialize(),
    dataType : 'json',
    a sync : false,
    success: function(response){
        if(response.status  === true){
            var error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">this record already exist</div>';
            jQuery('.form1ErrorMsg').html(error);
            return false;
        }else{
            alert('test');
            //return true;
        }             
    },
    error: function(){
       return false;
    }           
 });
   //return false;
});
```

**function.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['ActionToCall'])){
   $Action = $_POST['ActionToCall'];
   switch($Action){
       default:{
          break;
       }
       case 'chkDuplicatChiefInvigilator':{
          require_once('../../class/staff.class.php'); 
          require_once('../../class/user.class.php'); 
          $staff = new staffmanager();
          $users = new usermanager();
          $result=$staff->getDuplicatChiefInvigilator($_POST);
          if(!empty($result)){
             $output['status']=1;
          }else{
          $output['status']=0;
        }
        print json_encode($output,true);
        die;
      }
}
```

Comment: you should remove space between `data Type` and `a sync`

Answer (score 0):

Look at your syntax error:

```
dataType : 'json',
async : false,
```